# MySQL 5.7 vs 5.6: Index usage wrong at first, but "automagically" fixed weeks later

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, relational-database

**Context:**

I have a MySQL 5.6 as master, that have two replicas, one of them is also a MySQL 5.6 instance and other is a MySQL 5.7. Heavy queries are distributed evenly across the two replicas.

The 5.6 Replica is up and running for about 2 months, the 5.7 is newer, running about two weeks.

Using AWS RDS.

**Weird Behaviour:**

Just after the creation, I noticed that some queries were much slower at 5.7 because of “wrong index usage”, as shown by comparing the `EXPLAIN` result on both versions. Even some queries that had an `USE INDEX` clause, seemed to have no effect on 5.7 database.

Giving that it was a fresh new replica, I thought: “Maybe index statistics aren’t up to date?“.

Not the case. I have a routine that runs “analyse table” for every table on the system overnight at the master DB, so index statistics should be fine. I can confirm that the “analyse table” statement is successfully being replicated by checking the `last_update` on the replicas `mysql.innodb_index_stats`.

But some days have passed by, and **without any work on my side**, the bad queries started to use the right indexes! All fixed. No work done. Crazy day.

**Questions:**

1. What could affect the choice for a specific query execution plan? Index statistics aren’t the only thing?
2. Is there any “caching/warming up” stuff, that over two weeks of actual work could make **The Optimiser** change his mind?
3. Shouldn’t “analyse table” be enough to guarantee that both queries would have the same execution plan?
4. What else can explain that after two weeks of executions, the MySQL 5.7 starts to work same way as MySQL 5.6?

Remember, both databases were REPLICAS from the SAME SOURCE that receive EVENLY DISTRIBUTED traffic.

**SQL Example:**

The following query (this is an obfuscated version), was using the BAD index, and one day later it was using the GOOD index. Just like Magic™.

```
SELECT sale.number,
       seller.id,
       seller.name,
       sale.id,
       COALESCE(billed_amount, 0),
       COALESCE(billing.tax_id, '---'),
       billing.date,
       CASE COALESCE(sale.seller_name_2, '') WHEN '' THEN sale.seller_name_1 ELSE sale.seller_name_2 END,
       sale.business_id,
       sale.business_name,
       sale.total
FROM app_billing billing
         JOIN app_sale sale ON billing.sale_id = sale.id
         JOIN app_seller seller ON seller.id = sale.seller_id
WHERE billing.tenant_id = 515
  AND billing.removed = FALSE
  AND billing.date BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-31'
  AND sale.status = 2
  AND sale.seller_id IN (368);

-- MySQL 5.7 (BAD, really bad estimate and counter intuitive decision [should definitely be a range scan])
-- 1st step: There are only one seller with ID 368, so thats right.
-- 2nd step: 692 is pretty accurate, there are 695 sales for the seller ID 368.
-- 3rd step: This is tricky. There are a total of 270776 billing records that matches the 695 sale_ids from the previous step. 65% of the matches, have only one correspondence, but the remaining 35% have between 1000 and 5000 correspondences. Average would be 1360.
-- Estimated total number of processed records: 942000~.
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | seller  | NULL | const | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY       | 4 | const   | 1   | 100  | NULL |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sale    | NULL | ref   | PRIMARY,idx_seller_id                  | idx_seller_id | 4 | const   | 692 | 10   | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | billing | NULL | ref   | idx_sale_id,idx_tenant_id_removed_date | idx_sale_id   | 4 | sale.id | 2   | 2.16 | Using where |

-- MySQL 5.6 (GOOD, using range scan)
-- 1st step: There are only one seller with ID 368, so thats right.
-- 2nd step: 421 is almost perfect. There are actually 422 billing records across the date '2020-08-01' AND '2020-08-31' for the tenant_id 515 that arent removed.
-- 3rd step: That's right. There's only one sale correspondence per billing,
-- Estimated total number of processed records: 421.
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | seller  | const  | PRIMARY                                | PRIMARY                    | 4 | const           | 1   | NULL |
| 1 | SIMPLE | billing | range  | idx_sale_id,idx_tenant_id_removed_date | idx_tenant_id_removed_date | 9 | NULL            | 421 | Using index condition |
| 1 | SIMPLE | sale    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_seller_id                  | PRIMARY                    | 4 | billing.sale_id | 1   | Using where |
```

Comment: The execution plan (and hence the indices used in it) depends on the table statistic. Which may be inaccurate. In your case I see that the optimizer selects wrong tables scanning order - ANALYSE TABLE or FORCE INDEX cannot help in this case, reorder the tables in FROM clause of your query and use STRAIGHT_JOIN.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: When that `IN` has more than one item, the evaluation is likely to be quite different.

Comment: Getting the show create table would be tricky. I would need to obfuscate all the output before putting in here. About the `IN`, for sure it would change. But my point is that the statement, had two different execution plans, in two days, without any structural change (supposedly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL 5.7 and later suffer quite badly from a query optimizer heisenbug, which makes it unpredictably pick an egregiously bad execution plan. It sounds like you are falling foul of that. I have seen this sort of inconsistent, unpredictable behaviour on *every* 5.7 installation I have seen to date (more than I can hope to enumerate).

Regarding your specific questions:

1. Only the stats *should* be making a difference. However, the query plan was always also prone to getting confused when there is a large number of indexes in a table (more than approximately 10). And then there is the heisenbug I mentioned above.
2. No, but table statistics are maintained all the time in the background. It sounds like it finally got the data distribution estimation right - eventually.
3. It should - but often isn't. You may want to look at the following settings:

   innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages
   innodb_stats_persistent
4. optimizer_switch settings. You may want to try setting this on 5.7 to the same flag set that you have on 5.6. it sometimes helps (but not too often).

Comment: Thanks for the insights, I gave a look in the `optimizer_switch` and I got some good results playing with it. Specially: `condition_fanout_filter`, which turning off got me really good results (responsible for the weird explain plans). I'll keep debuging, but after all my reading and your conclusion, I would say that MySQL 5.7 have some mysterious moves under the hood. :P

Comment: Not just 5.7, but all versions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why the statistics might be slightly different, leading to a different explain plan.

Since the `WHERE` clause tests columns in more than one table, the Optimizer does not necessarily know which table to start with.  Sometimes it will pick the "wrong" table.

Rather than chasing the statistics and the Optimizer's choice, let's improve the indexes, thereby hopefully making the index enough faster to quell the question:

```
billing:  (tenant_id, sale_id, removed, date, tax_id)
billing:  (removed, tenant_id, date, sale_id, tax_id)
sale:  (status, seller_id)
```

That set of indexes should help regardless of which table it decides to start with.  The order of columns in each index is important.  (There are some variations that would work equally well.)

Examples of why the Optimizer might "do the wrong thing".

- If `billing.tenant_id = 515` occurs in only one row, then starting `billing` would probably be fast -- fetch one row, then join to get the row(s) from the other table.
- Similarly, if `sale.status = 2` occurs infrequently, `sale` would be a better first choice.

There are no statistics to achieve the above.  What there is:  "There are *about* 100 distinct `tenent_id` values out of 5000 rows."  That is, the Optimizer will *assume* that `tenant_id=515` occurs in 50 rows.

Note:  I said "about".  This is because `ANALYZE` does not (assuming a large InnoDB table) look at every value in the table.  Instead, it takes a sample. (Look for "number of dives" in the documentation.)

**Some things that can lead Primary and Replica to act differently**

- When were the stats last updated?  There is nothing to synchronize the updating.
- The stats involve "random" probes.  Hence slight (or big) variations can occur.
- In some situations a slight change in the stats can lead to a big difference in the query plan chosen -- typically between a table scan and using an index.  The Optimizer *tries* to have this quantum change at the point where there is not much difference in performance, but it can be wrong.
- Presumably different `SELECTs` are un on different Replicas.  `SELECTs` can interact with the writes coming through replication.  This can lead to block splits (etc) happening at different times and/or different places in the table.  This can indirectly impact the stats.
- Etc.

Comment: Is this "Sometimes it will pick the wrong table." behaviour non-deterministic by design? Just like sort order without "sort by clause"? I can live with that, just wanted to confirm that this is how the life of a MySQL DBA should be. :P

Comment: @IsraelFonseca - It is deterministic.  But it is based on _inadequate_ statistics.  Example:  `SELECT * FROM t WHERE x>0 LIMIT 4;`  (and no indexes) -- If the first few rows have x>0, then scanning forward would be optimal.  But if they are only at the end of the table, doing a reverse scan would be much better.  `ANALYZE TABLE` says what percentage of rows ..., it does not say where they are in the table.  Nor whether one value is more frequent than another.

Comment: @IsraelFonseca - And I added to my Answer to explain it a different way.

Comment: Very late answer on my part, but thanks for the clarifications Rick. I can see now how the statistics could lead to a bad execution plan giving your examples (mainly about sampling issues). Nevertheless, I still wondered why the REPLICAS (same row distribution) would have different plans, but as @Gordan pointed out, the MySQL 5.7 optimizers are different than 5.6. After changing it, the plans got similar again, which makes sense.

Comment: @IsraelFonseca - I added some more hand-waving.

Comment: Thanks again @RickJames. I think that the "random probes" could be the explanation that better explains what I saw. Both replicas got the "analyze table" running at every table, at same time, but I can understand now that could happen edge cases that plays against the human sanity. :) Btw, where do you get this kind of knowledge? Is there a book on the subject, or is the source code the only book available?

Comment: @IsraelFonseca - 20 years of using MySQL/MariaDB.  Attending conferences (no longer in person).  Lots of online stuff -- the manual; Percona stuff; other blogs (less reliable).  Experimentation.

Comment: @IsraelFonseca - Search for "innodb random probes"; _some_ of the sites will explain _that_ further.  _Probably_ the manual mentions "random probes", perhaps under `ALTER`.